# Grey(disabled) text in Visual C++ 2010 Express code. What does it mean? How do I resolve it?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Some portion of the C code gets greyed in the IDE. I'm unable to figure out why. This happened in many other sections of the code as well. Some of errors I'm getting show that this code isn't getting recognized by the compiler. Could anyone help me by suggesting what is the cause for greying and also how to resolve it?
I've attached a snapshot the IDE text editor window. Hope it helps!

[image: Snapshot of IDE code editor: 1]

[image]

Comment: Your link returns an error: "The requested URL could not be retrieved", some kind of "read error" was encountered. Why not sure our built-in image uploading service instead of your PhotoBucket account hidden behind an obfuscated `goo.gl` link?

Comment: @Cody, no repro here. For what it's worth, both the link in the question and the one in the comment work for me.

Comment: @Cody: when I posted the question, stackoverflow didnt allow me to add the picture(i didnt have enough reputation since im a newbie to stackoverflow)..so i uploaded on photobucket and shortened it cos the photobucket one was too long. Im able to open the files too. No idea why you aren't. I'll add the pic in the question..hold on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code editor is sophisticated enough to understand that the `_32_` preprocessor symbol is left undefined in your current build configuration (and is not defined by previously included code).

To reflect that, it grays out the dependent code to point out that it won't be compiled (or even seen by the compiler).

Platform-dependent code like this should almost always be left as is. If you want the grayed-out parts to be compiled, you will have to switch your target platform to 32 bits, or possibly `#define _32_` before including the code in your screenshot.

Comment: But I don't understand why this portion is being greyed out.. (http://goo.gl/ac5b7)

Comment: @Shambavi, you should look up [#ifdef / #else / #endif](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a1b21sf.aspx) and make yourself familiar with the concept behind them. In your second screenshot, the `#ifdef` (or `#if`) part that is not shown has a condition that evaluates to `true`, therefore the code before `#else` will be compiled and the code after will not. It's the somewhat opposite of your first example.

Comment: Alright!Thanks a ton! And yep..I'll read up a bit more on the preprocessor directives
PS: I changed the link to display the #ifdef portion as well)